# Which characters ARE allowed in file/folder names in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, special-characters

Which characters ***ARE*** allowed in file/folder names in SharePoint?

Comment: I am asking the OPPOSITE of that question.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the list of characters which you can't use as per MSFT; the rest you can.

**File names**

You cannot use the following characters anywhere in a file name:

```
Tilde (~)
Number sign (#)
Percent (%)
Ampersand (&)
Asterisk (*)
Braces ({ })
Backslash (\)
Colon (:)
Angle brackets (< >)
Question mark (?)
Slash (/)
Plus sign (+)
Pipe (|)
Quotation mark (")
```

- You cannot use the period character consecutively in the middle of a file name.
- You cannot use the period character at the end of a file name.
- You cannot start a file name by using the period character.
- If you use an underscore character (`_`) at the beginning of a file name, the file will be a hidden file.
- File names and folder names may not end with any of the following strings:

  .files
  _files
  -Dateien
  _fichiers
  _bestanden
  _file
  _archivos
  -filer
  _tiedostot
  _pliki
  _soubory
  _elemei
  _ficheiros
  _arquivos
  _dosyalar
  _datoteke
  _fitxers
  _failid
  _fails
  _bylos
  _fajlovi
  _fitxategiak

In addition, file names and folder names cannot start with the “*vti*” string, such as the followings:

```
_vti_cnf
_vti_pvt
_vti_bin
_vti_txt
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/905231

Comment: According to the link, the ban for `+` sign is only for site names, subsite names, or site group names

Comment: Manually tested with SP2016 on premise:
`&{}+~` are allowed for file names.
`You cannot use the period character consecutively in the middle of a file name.` - not confirmed.
`You cannot start a file name by using the period character.` - not confirmed.
`If you use an underscore character (_) at the beginning of a file name, the file will be a hidden file.` - not confirmed.
`file names and folder names may not end with any of the following strings` - not case sensitive.
`file names and folder names cannot start with the “vti” string` - case sensitive.